# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#create Couldn't find Account without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I keep getting this error and I have looked at many other questions to try to find an answer but I haven´t been able to. Can anyone help me?

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#create
Couldn't find Account without an ID
```

**My models**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
end
```

**User controller**

```
def create
  @account = Account.find(params[:id])
  @user = @account.users.build(user_params)
  authorize @user
if @user.save
  redirect_to users_path, notice: 'Successfully created User'
else
  redirect_to users_path, alert: 'Failed to create User'
end
```

**the form**

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :autofocus => true, class: 'form-control' %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :account %>
    <%= collection_select(:user, :account_id, Account.all, :id, :name, {prompt: true, class: 'form-control'}) %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
  </p>
  <%= f.submit 'Create User', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

What I am trying to do is select an account in the form when creating a new `User`.

Comment: Please post the `params` generated on the form submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the way you've set up your form, the account id will be in

```
params[:user][:account_id]
```

So use

```
@account = Account.find(params[:user][:account_id])
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. The error is gone, unfortunately `@user` is not saving and I am getting `alert: "Failed to create user"`

Comment: I try from the console:`a = User.new({"account_id"=>"1"})` and then `a.save` but I get `false`. Ok I am going to make new question thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your code wills end the parameters in a nested manner. So params[:user] is the main hash and to fetch other details you need to use that hash instead of params.

```
params[:user][:account_id]
```

would work fine.